# How to parameterize SecureString pipeline parameter in Azure Data Factory? So it can be set during CICD

Tags: azure, parameters, azure-devops, azure-data-factory, azure-rm-template

I have certain parameters in my pipeline in Azure Data Factory. Three parameters are String type but one is SecureString:

[image]

I have git enabled with ADF, and when I publish my master so that it can generate ARM templates with these parameters parameterized but I get this issue:

1) If my sasToken parameter which is secureString do not have default value than it do not get parameterized. (I also got this issue when my string datatype parameters where not having default value. So giving a default value is must because it parameterize the default value).

2) And If I give a default value to SecureString parameter and publish my master than it gives me following error:

**Parameters of type SecureString cannot have a default value when using Git mode, they must be fetched at runtime through Azure Key Vault or set when triggering the pipeline manually.**

In short I want to parameterize storageAccountName and sasToken and there value will be set during CICD, I am able to parameterize storageAccountName but not able to parameterize sasToken (with empty default value because it is not allowing default value for SecureString type).

My arm-template-parameters-definition.json is:

```
"Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines": {
    "properties": {
      "activities": [
        {
          "typeProperties": {           
            "degreeOfParallelism": "=:degreeOfParallelism:int",
            "parameters": {
                "*": "="
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "parameters": {
                    "storageAccountName": {
                        "defaultValue": "="
                    },
                    "sasToken": {
                        "defaultValue": "="
                    }
                }
    }
```

ARM template getting generated by Data Factory has following json for this pipeline parameters section:

```
}
                ],
                "parameters": {
                    "stageName": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "defaultValue": "FEATURE_STAGE"
                    },
                    "folderPath": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "defaultValue": "/enterprisedata/ProcessedFeatureData"
                    },
                    "storageAccountName": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "defaultValue": "[parameters('PL_Snowflake_CustomActivities_properties_parameters_storageAccountName_defaultValue')]"
                    },
                    "sasToken": {
                        "type": "securestring"
                    }
                },
                "annotations": []
```

So storageAccountName is parameterized but not sasToken... And I need to parameterize it, I will set there value in CICD.. Please guide.

Comment: Are you trying to grant ADF access to a storage account you control? Based upon your description it sounds like you want to dynamically generate the sasToken parameters value based on the storage account provisioned?

Comment: No, In this pipeline I have azure function activity and I need to pass SAS to my azure function through body. The issue is before making a call to azure function, I need its value. As its a type of key to Storage account so we developers do not have its value and its value is present in the release pipeline. I what I need is to parameterize the SAS parameter like storageAccountName is parameterized, so that I can set its value during deployment.

Comment: How are you deploying this?  If the ARM template is being used by Azure DevOps it can grab the secure string through the variable being entered into Azure DevOps as a secret and passed in as an override parameter.  Another potential option is the SAS key be stored in an Azure Key Vault and as part of the deployment call Key Vault to retrieve the secret. Also are [Managed Identities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview) a possibility? This could eliminate the need for a SAS key